# keras divide inputs by a constant without using ImageDataGenerator

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Hi I was wondering if there is a way in which I can use a layer to divide a tensor by a constant in keras within the model instead of using ImageDataGenerator e.g.

```
sequence = [
    keras.Input(shape=(224,224,3)),
    <------ DIVIDES ALL THE INPUTS BY 255
    keras.layers.Dense(32, activation="softmax"),
]
model = keras.Sequential(sequence)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `keras.Lambda` layer.

```
sequence = [
    Input(shape=(224,224,3)),
    Lambda(lambda x: x/255.0),
    Dense(32, activation="softmax"),
]
```

This in fact produces the following output shape. `(None, 224, 224, 32)`. This is not the shape you want if you're doing image classification problem for example. Then you just need `(None, 32)`. The above shape can be totally fine depending on the problem you're trying to solve. But just pointing out in case it's a mistake. You can use the `Flatten` layer as follows.

```
sequence = [
    Input(shape=(224,224,3)),
    Lambda(lambda x: x/255.0),
    Flatten(),
    Dense(32, activation="softmax"),
]
```